# How to unblock someone in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I use Empathy as my default messenger. I had blocked someone in Empathy but now I want to unblock him. The person whom I blocked is using Gmail.

So, how to unblock that person?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

Open the Contacts window (empaty itself).
In the application menu you have Edit-Blocked contacts.
There is the list of blocked contacts. Select one and click on minus button below the list.